# Definitions of map and tf using turtlebot3

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, turtlebot3, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using turtlebot3 and SLAM.
My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and ROS1 melodic.
I have the questions about /tf and /map.
I want to implement subscriber callback, but I don't know the type of the argument.
What are the map and tf type definitions and required header files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357244/definitions-of-map-and-tf-using-turtlebot3/) by [dapt](https://answers.ros.org/users/56574/dapt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2020-07-15**:
Subscriber to what? Give more details on your problem please

**Comment by [dapt](https://answers.ros.org/users/56574/dapt/) on 2020-07-15**:
I am using turtlebot3 and its SLAM g-mapping. I see /tf and /map on rqt_graph, but I want to subscribe to them on another node that created cpp. At this time, the subscriber created with cpp receives msg by callback, but I do not know the type of these msg.

```
void Callback(T msg){}
```

I don't know what should come in the T part.

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2020-07-16**:
In another terminal type `rostopic info /topic_name` and you can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check more info of any topic/service from terminal by

`rostopic info <topic_name>`

`roservice info<service_name>

further more to check the structure of message you can

`rosmsg show <message_name>`

hope this help's you.

---

Originally posted by [Abelard](https://answers.ros.org/users/56660/abelard/) with karma: 26 on 2020-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1